# What service is hosting the IISCrashHangAgent

Tags: iis

The IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool installs the IISCrashHangAgent. What service is hosting the agent?

Answer (score 1):

IIS Crash/Hang Agent is an obsolete tool, which still is available here

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=01c4f89d-cc68-42ba-98d2-0c580437efcf&displaylang=en

But to debug IIS problems, now you should use DebugDiag

http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en